# Extracting text (filename) out of a file with Powershell if line contains search pattern

Tags: regex, string, powershell

I´ve got a problem... I´ve got a file where the content looks like

```
IMPORT ("$(#T_Company-BAG)\KSAKTE13","06141030.eou")
IMPORT ("$(#T_Company-Gesmbh)\KSAKTE13","06141032.eou")
IMPORT ("$(#T_Company-ITALIA)\KSAKTE13","06141038.eou")
IMPORT ("$(#T_Company-ITALIA)\KSAKTE13","06141045.eou")
IMPORT ("$(#T_Company-ITALIA)\RWRECH13","06141512.eou")
```

The thing i want to do is to extract the file name (`*.eou`) which is inside the last quotes and only the file names which line contains the string `T_Company-ITALIA`...

The first part, extracting all lines containing the search pattern isn´t so difficult...

```
gc -Path C:\Scripts\Easyarchiv\level2.ebt | Select-String -Pattern T_Company-ITALIA
```

But i don´t know how to get only the file names (`*.eou`) out of the already selected lines...

Now I´m searching for a regex which can extract this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option without using `Select-String`:

```
Get-Content file.txt | 
where {$_ -match 'T_Company-ITALIA'} | 
foreach { $_ -replace '^.+,"(.+)"\).*$','$1'}
```

Comment: Hi Shay... thank you for your post... With this code I´m getting the lines I need... Do you also know the solution to my second part of my post?!? I need to extract the file name(06141038.eou) which is included in each line... It´s an 8-digit name with .eou file extension.. So i´m able to write these file names to a file or use it in a variable for further processing

Comment: You should get the file names with the example I posted. 06141038.eou, 
06141045.eou and 06141512.eou

Comment: Unfortunately not... I´m getting the complete lines

Comment: PS F:\scripts\Easyarchiv> Get-Content file.txt | where {$_ -match 'T_Company-ITALIA'} | foreach { $_ -replace '^.+,"(.+)
"\).+$','$1'}
IMPORT ("$(#T_Company-ITALIA)\KSAKTE13","06141038.eou")
IMPORT ("$(#T_Company-ITALIA)\KSAKTE13","06141045.eou")
IMPORT ("$(#T_Company-ITALIA)\RWRECH13","06141512.eou")

Comment: Yes... It´s running and returning only the file names... Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of `Select-String`:

```
... | ? { $_ -match 'T_Company-ITALIA.*?,"(.*?)"' } | % { $matches[1] }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to stay away from regular expressions (which can be hard to read, debug, and understand) you could do this:

```
gc file.txt | 
  foreach { 
    $splitArray = $_ -split '"'; # split at the quotation marks
    if ($splitArray[1] -match "T_Company-ITALIA") 
      {$splitArray[3]}
  }
```